# My Flask API call works locally but not when I deploy it to Heroku, what are possible reasons?

Tags: python, heroku

I made a route in my flask app that pings an external endpoint upon getting triggered. It's been working fine all along locally when I ping it from postman, on two different computers in fact I've tested it, without using any headers. But once deployed to Heroku it just times out and I get this message:

---

### heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=POST path="/gettodaysinfo" host=model.herokuapp.com request_id=b8b7c7d9-4a46-400b-b144-025a3418a92c fwd="73.205.154.81" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=30001ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https

Does anyone know what could be happening here and how to even debug this?

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

What are you using this endpoint for and can you show the code please ? I had a similar issue with Heroku and Node.js turns out I didn't configure the config vars in the Heroku settings.